# Failure to start Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I start zeppelin o It starts on port 8080, it says port already in use. I tried changing port in zeppelin in config files, in `zeppelin-site.xml.template` made it too in `zeppelin-env.sh.template` adding the env line for the same port.

When I start zeppelin, I get OK, but if I see the open ports, It doesn't appear 8050 anywhere, so looks like It is still trying to deploy on port 8080

This is error I get when I click `zeppelin.cmd`

```
/zeppelin/interpreter/ignite/zeppelin-ignite_2.11-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-settin
g.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,111] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/zeppelin-jdbc-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,126] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/kylin/zeppelin-kylin-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,281] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/lens/zeppelin-lens-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,431] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/livy/zeppelin-livy-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,466] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/md/zeppelin-markdown-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:49,754] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/pig/zeppelin-pig-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
 WARN [2018-05-06 07:33:49,794] ({main} Interpreter.java[register]:406) - Static
 initialization is deprecated for interpreter sql, You should change it to use i
nterpreter-setting.json in your jar or interpreter/{interpreter}/interpreter-set
ting.json
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:49,794] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:305
) - Interpreter psql.sql found. class=org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlI
nterpreter
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:52,889] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/python/zeppelin-python-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.jso
n
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:53,234] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/sh/zeppelin-shell-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:55,279] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerI
nterpreterFromResource]:382) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/C
:/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.11-0.7.3.jar!/interpreter-setting.
json
DEBUG [2018-05-06 07:33:55,284] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:320
) - Registered: psql.sql -> org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter
. Properties: {postgresql.password={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValu
e=, description=The PostgreSQL user password}, postgresql.max.result={envName=nu
ll, propertyName=null, defaultValue=1000, description=Max number of SQL result t
o display.}, postgresql.user={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=gpad
min, description=The PostgreSQL user name}, postgresql.url={envName=null, proper
tyName=null, defaultValue=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/, description=The URL
 for PostgreSQL.}, postgresql.driver.name={envName=null, propertyName=null, defa
ultValue=org.postgresql.Driver, description=    JDBC Driver Name}}
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,289] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name ignite
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,289] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name python
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,294] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name jdbc
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,294] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name psql
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,294] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name lens
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,294] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name pig
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,299] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name flink
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,299] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name angular
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,299] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name livy
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,304] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name file
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,304] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name elasticsearch
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,304] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name cassandra
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,304] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name sh
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,309] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name spark
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,309] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name md
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,309] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name alluxio
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,309] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name bigquery
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,314] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name hbase
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,314] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:337
) - InterpreterSettingRef name kylin
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,450] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group md : id=2DEPH6PYC, name=md
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,453] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group psql : id=2DD7ZJKPA, name=psql
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,457] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group python : id=2DCAMH4GY, name=python
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,463] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group file : id=2DDZH8WCB, name=file
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,472] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group elasticsearch : id=2DE3BGT7H, name=elasticsearch
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,476] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group bigquery : id=2DEVZXKAG, name=bigquery
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,480] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group hbase : id=2DC4M79BE, name=hbase
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,482] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group sh : id=2DD1MA4VU, name=sh
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,482] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group pig : id=2DCNP1WD2, name=pig
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,482] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group alluxio : id=2DC7G4QW3, name=alluxio
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,482] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group livy : id=2DEQ54GYT, name=livy
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,487] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group flink : id=2DDWBXQYG, name=flink
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,487] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group spark : id=2DF55VV2T, name=spark
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,487] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group ignite : id=2DCJEAGTV, name=ignite
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,492] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group kylin : id=2DC5T3GZV, name=kylin
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,492] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group angular : id=2DFHJM4RD, name=angular
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,492] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group lens : id=2DC9V3E9V, name=lens
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,492] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group jdbc : id=2DEECFK3N, name=jdbc
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,497] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:366
) - InterpreterSetting group cassandra : id=2DCH1RQVX, name=cassandra
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,537] ({main} InterpreterFactory.java[<init>]:130) - s
hiroEnabled: false
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:55,858] ({main} VfsLog.java[info]:138) - Using "C:\Users
\Weltinfo\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,055] ({main} GitNotebookRepo.java[<init>]:63) - Openi
ng a git repo at '/zeppelin/notebook'
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,578] ({main} NotebookAuthorization.java[loadFromFile]
:96) - C:\zeppelin\conf\notebook-authorization.json
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,581] ({main} Credentials.java[loadFromFile]:102) - C:
\zeppelin\conf\credentials.json
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,710] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:11
84) - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,720] ({main} SimpleThreadPool.java[initialize]:268) -
 Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,775] ({main} SchedulerSignalerImpl.java[<init>]:61) -
 Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignale
rImpl
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,798] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[<init>]:240) - Quar
tz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,802] ({main} RAMJobStore.java[initialize]:155) - RAMJ
obStore initialized.
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,806] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[initialize]:305) -
Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with ins
tanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persis
tence. and is not clustered.

 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,810] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:13
39) - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resourc
e file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,813] ({main} StdSchedulerFactory.java[instantiate]:13
43) - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:56,815] ({main} QuartzScheduler.java[start]:575) - Sched
uler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,388] ({main} FolderView.java[createFolder]:107) - Cre
ate folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,394] ({main} FolderView.java[createFolder]:107) - Cre
ate folder /
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,396] ({main} Folder.java[setParent]:168) - Set parent
 of / to /
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,397] ({main} Folder.java[setParent]:168) - Set parent
 of Zeppelin Tutorial to /
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,398] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2A9
4M5J1Z to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,456] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2BW
JFTXKJ to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,504] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2BY
EZ5EVK to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,528] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2C2
AUG798 to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,557] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2C3
5YU814 to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,574] ({main} Folder.java[addNote]:184) - Add note 2C5
7UKYWR to folder Zeppelin Tutorial
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:57,575] ({main} Notebook.java[<init>]:127) - Notebook in
dexing started...
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:58,305] ({main} LuceneSearch.java[addIndexDocs]:305) - I
ndexing 6 notebooks took 729ms
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:58,305] ({main} Notebook.java[<init>]:129) - Notebook in
dexing finished: 6 indexed in 0s
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:33:58,603] ({main} ServerImpl.java[initDestination]:94) - S
etting the server's publish address to be /
mai 06, 2018 7:33:58 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFOS: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.apache.zeppelin.rest
mai 06, 2018 7:33:58 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasse
s
INFOS: Root resource classes found:
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.SecurityRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.HeliumRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ConfigurationsRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.InterpreterRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRepoRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.CredentialRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi
  class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ZeppelinRestApi
mai 06, 2018 7:33:58 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFOS: No provider classes found.
mai 06, 2018 7:33:59 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImp
l _initiate
INFOS: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'

mai 06, 2018 7:34:00 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
AVERTISSEMENT: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or pr
ovider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppel
in.rest.CredentialRestApi.getCredentials(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOExce
ption,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppel
in.rest.InterpreterRestApi.listInterpreter(java.lang.String), should not consume
 any entity.
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.ze
ppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.createNote(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOExcept
ion, with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.ze
ppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.getNoteList() throws java.io.IOException, with URI t
emplate, "/", is treated as a resource method
 INFO [2018-05-06 07:34:00,216] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Star
ted o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@140e5a13{/,file:/C:/zeppelin/webapps/webapp/,AVAILABLE
}{C:\zeppelin\zeppelin-web-0.7.3.war}
 WARN [2018-05-06 07:34:00,227] ({main} AbstractLifeCycle.java[setFailed]:212) -
 FAILED ServerConnector@1317b708{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException
: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:32
1)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNet
workConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java
:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:18
9)
 WARN [2018-05-06 07:34:00,233] ({main} AbstractLifeCycle.java[setFailed]:212) -
 FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@44a6a68e: java.net.BindException: Addres
s already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:32
1)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNet
workConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java
:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:18
9)
ERROR [2018-05-06 07:34:00,236] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:194) - Error w
hile running jettyServer
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:32
1)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNet
workConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java
:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:18
9)
```

Answer (score 3):

"zeppelin-site.xml.template" and "zeppelin-env.sh.template" are not the files that are actual used when running Zeppelin. They are - as their name suggest - templates that should help to build the actual configuration files. They should not be changed.

Instead, create a copy of these files that are named "zeppelin-site.xml" or "zeppelin-env.sh" respectively and adopt these files according to your needs. During the next restart of Zeppelin the new settings should be picked up.